# Download link from ForeignKey model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-2.2

I would like to create an attachment on every post of my blog. Then I've do this:

```
class FileUpload(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=70)
    file = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("single_file", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})


class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(max_length=70)
    .
    .
    .
    attachment = models.ForeignKey(
        FileUpload, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="related_attachment", 
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        )
```

Inside the template of a single post I've put this:

```
  {% if blogpost.attachment %}
  <hr>
  <div>
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ attachment.get_absolute_url }}" rule="button">
        Download
    </a>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
```

But I see that the `href` is empty and I can't download the attachment. The if condition work fine because the button didn't appear if the post don't have the attachment.

What is the right way to put a download link inside my download button?

Comment: Have you tried to log something in the `get_absolute_url`? is it actually executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you have a typo:

replace `attachment.get_absolute_url`

with

`blogpost.attachment.get_absolute_url`

Answer (score 0):

Well, a couple of things. Firstly, it seems from the `if` statement that you're passing in `blogpost`from the view, which would mean that you need to reference `blogpost.attachment`.

Your url should probably be referenced like this anyway though:

```
<a href="{% url '<app_name>:<link_name>' blogpost.attachement.pk %}">Download</a>
```